# Ruby: inheritance or something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, model

I've a quick and quite basic question to ask.
I would like to create a new model which has a parameter that can be one of several model types.
Ex: the param 'targeted_object' can be either an instance of Model A or an instance of Model B.
For the moment I don't think I need a similar behavior for Model A and Model B, so my first guess is to create a Master model for Model A and Model B named TargetableObject: create inheritance.
But is it the best way to do this or I need to make something else regarding that I presume for now no related behavior for Master object children?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like [single table inheritance](https://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) is what you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer I will read it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, [Polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) could be what you need.

From the rails guides:

> With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a product model.

Comment: It's not a belong property but more a generic type as T in Java.